# How to use a function that belongs to another method?

Tags: flutter, dart

I would like to know how I could call my _submitData method in _Appbar() for example

My method allows me to validate fields and send them to my database and I would like to add in my appbar a button to activate this method

```
_buildBody() {
    TextEditingController namecontroller = TextEditingController();
    TextEditingController firstnamecontroller = TextEditingController();
    TextEditingController jobcontroller = TextEditingController();
    TextEditingController phonenumbercontroller = TextEditingController();
    TextEditingController emailcontroller = TextEditingController();

    void _submitData() {
      String enteredname = namecontroller.text;
      String enteredfirstname = firstnamecontroller.text;
      String enteredjob = jobcontroller.text;
      String enteredphonenumber = phonenumbercontroller.text;
      String enteredemail = emailcontroller.text;

      final firstSettings = Settings(
        name: enteredname,
        firstname: enteredfirstname,
        job: enteredjob,
        phonenumber: enteredphonenumber,
        email: enteredemail,
      );

      void _noModificateForm() {
        if (enteredname.isEmpty) {
          enteredname = widget.settingsList.name.toString();
        }
        if (enteredfirstname.isEmpty) {
          enteredfirstname = widget.settingsList.firstname.toString();
        }
        if (enteredjob.isEmpty) {
          enteredjob = widget.settingsList.job.toString();
        }
        if (enteredphonenumber.isEmpty) {
          enteredphonenumber = widget.settingsList.phonenumber.toString();
        }
        if (enteredemail.isEmpty) {
          enteredemail = widget.settingsList.email.toString();
        }

        final allSettings = Settings(
          name: enteredname,
          firstname: enteredfirstname,
          job: enteredjob,
          phonenumber: enteredphonenumber,
          email: enteredemail,
        );

        boxSettings.putAt(0, allSettings);
      }

      if (boxSettings.isEmpty) {
        boxSettings.add(firstSettings);
      } else {
        _noModificateForm();
      }
      Navigator.pop(context);
    }
```

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/svg.dart';
import 'package:hive_flutter/hive_flutter.dart';
import 'package:medicalnote/models/listsettings.dart';
import 'dart:math' as math;

import '../component/component.dart';

class SettingsProfilePage extends StatefulWidget {
  final Settings settingsList;
  const SettingsProfilePage(this.settingsList, {Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<SettingsProfilePage> createState() => _SettingsProfilePageState();
}

class _SettingsProfilePageState extends State<SettingsProfilePage> {
  late Box<Settings> boxSettings;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    boxSettings = Hive.box('Settings');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: _appBar(),
        body: _buildBody(),
        bottomNavigationBar: _saveSettings(size));
  }

_appBar(){}
_buildBody(){....
```

If I can't do it in a simple way I'll have to redesign the whole architecture of this page that's why I'm calling you if you have an idea :)

Thanks

Comment: how do you want to use it and where?

Comment: I would like to use it in appBar for example and I will just call it with a textbutton